# Material-UI Tabs not working in JavaFX WebView

Tags: javafx, tabs, material-ui

I have a webpage using React and Material-UI that I would like to embed in my desktop application using JavaFX's WebView. However, when I try to do so, Tabs from Material-UI are not working as expected. The first time I click a tab it works as intended and the content of that tab is displayed and the tab is marked as the active one. Thereafter it stops working and you can't switch tab.

To reproduce the problem the following code should suffice:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        webEngine.load("http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs");

        pane.setCenter(webView);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Application.launch(TabTest.class);
    }
}
```

Observations so far:

- Tabs works for regular web browsers.
- After it stops working the entire web page seems to respond to clicks (the Material-UI click animation is triggered everywhere). I added logging to the Material-UI Tab component and onTouchTap was triggered on the Tab selected from the first click wherever I clicked.

Does anyone know what the problem might be and if there is any way to fix it? Or should I file this as a JavaFX bug?

Comment: I filed a bug to oracle http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8161912. I got it up and running with Java 9 but it seems that the webkit version in Java 8 is simply too old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem for Java 8. add

```
{
display: inline;
position: relative;
}
```

to the style of each Tab